# Google Book orderby bug?

Tags: google-api, google-books

I'm really confused with the Google Books API, and I strongly believe that the "orderBy" is bugged, this is the official API documentation:

https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using#st_params

and this is an example of a query using orderBy filter:

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=flowers&orderBy=newest

on the documentation is mentioned that it should be from newest to oldest based on **published date** while clearly the API returns an order that's wrong.

Any clues?

Comment: We cannot provide product specific support and this is not the correct place to report bugs in anything. If, after reading and understanding the documentation for a product (which it seems like you have, and I agree that the behaviour of the API does not appear to match that described in the documentation) you need to contact the product specific support/forums - the Books API has a dedicated forum that can be found [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/books-api). Voting to close as off topic.